# How to stop failed login attempts by a domain

Tags: ssh, iptables, brute-force-attacks

I'm getting a ton of bruteforce attacks today from a domain rather then an IP. I tracked down the websites IP address and blocked it but I am still getting the bruteforce warnings. Can I some how use iptables to block a domain name?

```
alumni.xjtu.edu.cn
```

Comment: brute force against what? HTTP? SSH? FTP?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff  I would guess SSH, but i'm not sure. This is the message I get. 5 failed login attempts to account root (system) -- Large number of attempts from this IP: alumni.xjtu.edu.cn

Comment: I've been getting them every 5 minutes for the last 10 hours. Normally I block the IP and I'm good to go. @SpacemanSpiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider doing a reverse DNS query, then a whois query do determine the network block and finally just drop the whole network block.

Commands:

```
host alumni.xjtu.cn
alumni.xjtu.edu.cn has address 202.117.3.104

whois 202.117.3.104
inetnum:        202.117.0.0 - 202.117.63.255
netname:        XJTU-CN
descr:          Xian Jiaotong University
descr:          Xian
descr:          Shanxi Province
...

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --source 202.117.0.0/17 -j DROP
```

No more TCP connections from the whole university.

Comment: So basically run this line in putty? iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --source 202.117.0.0/17 -j DROP

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) to automatically detect and ban these brute-force login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Ban 202.117.3.104. This IP has a PTR record (reverse dns) and it resolves to alumni.xjtu.edu.cn.
[Reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work